# Activity Restarts onActivityResult(), after image selected from the SDCard

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an application where i go to select an image from the gallery, and return with the image to set it on the imageview. The problem is, when i set the 1st image, and again go to select the next image using the same button, the 1st image is gone, and current image is set as the 1st image. I have a linearlayout and i dynamically create the imageviews as the images are selected.

Below is my class, where i select the image on the button click btnSelectPhotosGallery, and then onActivityResult is there.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    int id = v.getId();
    Intent i;
    switch (id)
    {
            //image selection on this button click
    case R.id.btnSelectPhotosGallery:
        Intent intent = new Intent();

        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE)
        {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String imagePath = CommonMethods.getPath(ArticleForm2.this, selectedImageUri);
            File image = new File(imagePath);
            long sizeOfImage = ((image.length()/1024)/1024);
            if(sizeOfImage > 1.0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(ArticleForm2.this, "Image exceeding the Maximum Size(1 MB)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //coverPhotoSelected = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //imageCoverPhoto.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
                Bitmap bmp = getPreview(imagePath);
                ImageView img = new ImageView(ArticleForm2.this);
                img.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(300, 300));
                img.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                linearImages.addView(img);

            }
        }
    }
}


public Bitmap getPreview(String fileName) {
    File image = new File(fileName);

    BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bounds.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getPath(), bounds);
    if ((bounds.outWidth == -1) || (bounds.outHeight == -1)) {
        return null;
    }
    int originalSize = (bounds.outHeight > bounds.outWidth) ? bounds.outHeight
        : bounds.outWidth;
    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opts.inSampleSize = originalSize / 64;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getPath());
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting your images selected? How you are generating Dynamic `ImageView` ? Please show code of it.

Comment: atleast show your problem show we can help you..

Comment: @GrIsHu : I am setting the imageView in the else part of the onActivityResult, and then i add that view to the linear layout at the last line.

Comment: @Segi : Sir, my problem is, when the 1st image is set using onActivityResult, i again click the button btnSelectPhotosGallery, given in the code to select another image. When i return from selecting the 2nd image, the 1st image that was set using the onActivityResult is gone and replaced by the current image i select.

Comment: @Segi : so i am puzzled, i think activity is restarting when the onActivityResult is called.

Comment: Please tell me, if you need any more info. THanks in Advance.

Comment: @Stealz if you are set image into same imageview then obviously it will be replaced..

Comment: @Stealz the behaviour which is occuring in your is the only default behaviour because you are after all each time creating the new `ImageView` and setting the image on that `ImageView` so the previously created `Imageview` does not appear to you.

Comment: I am creating a new object evertime, @Segi and adding it to the layout, as you can see. So how can it be replaced?

Comment: I am creating a new object evertime, @GrIsHu and adding it to the layout, as you can see. So how can it be replaced?

Comment: Its not replaced its overridden with the old one @Stealz

Comment: @Stealz you are giving same width and height everytime..

Comment: @GrIsHu : If so, please tell me the correct way to implement it. You can write is as an answer. THanks in advance.

Comment: First let me know you want to show both images or just want to show the last selected image only in ImageView?

Comment: @GrIsHu : I want to select maximum 8 images in the linearlayout, so 8 times the onActivityResult would be called, and all the 8 should be visible in the linearlayout, not overriding any of it. THanks.

Comment: In your case you have to select multiple images once and pass it all in your activity and show it in ImageView. Calling onActivityResult multiple times is not feasible solution in this case.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/paramvir-b/AndroidGridViewCompatLib CustomGridView for this.

Comment: @GrIsHu : OK, i will try the above and check. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

in the OnClick-Method.
(An Activity launched with this will finish as soon as the user navigates away from it)

Comment: I don't want to restart the activity, i want to stop it from restarting when onActivityResult is called.

Comment: Are you setting any flags for this activity in the AndroidManifest?

Comment: No, no flags are set in the Manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Orientation change due to launching Camera Activity. Change like following code in your Manifest for calling Activity.

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```